# How to conduct logical tests or mathematical operations in parallel cells across multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of separate excel sheets with counts of the number of people attending events in a set of rooms during time increments for each day of the week.  Kind of like:

ROOM 101:

| TIME WINDOW | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 AM - 12:00 PM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 12:00 PM - 4:00 PM | 5 | 5 | 20 | 5 | 0 |
| 4:00 PM - 8:00 PM | 5 | 0 | 20 | 5 | 0 |

ROOM 102:

| TIME WINDOW | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 AM - 12:00 PM | 0 | 0 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| 12:00 PM - 4:00 PM | 8 | 0 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| 4:00 PM - 8:00 PM | 8 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 0 |

I wish to produce a new dataframe that reports for each day and time window the number of instances where the count was 0.  Which I would then use to create a seaborn heatmap.  In this example:

| TIME WINDOW | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 AM - 12:00 PM | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 12:00 PM - 4:00 PM | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 4:00 PM - 8:00 PM | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

After looping through the files and reading them in as dataframes, how could I do this?

Also, is there a way to populate lists of the zero rooms for each cell (day and time window). E.g. Friday 8:00 AM = [101,102]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eq` + `astype(int)`; then add the DataFrames:

```
out = df1.set_index('TIME WINDOW').eq(0).astype(int) + df2.set_index('TIME WINDOW').eq(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
                    MONDAY  TUESDAY  WEDNESDAY  THURSDAY  FRIDAY
TIME WINDOW                                                     
8:00 AM - 12:00 PM       2        2          1         0       2
12:00 PM - 4:00 PM       0        1          0         0       2
4:00 PM - 8:00 PM        0        1          0         0       2
```